# Create a constant variable if an "if statement" is satisfied

Tags: c++, if-statement, constants

I would like to know if we can create a constant variable inside an if statement. So the variable starts to exist from that time in the program.

For example:

```
if (true)  //this statement happens ONLY ONCE
{
      const variable = x;
}
```

Comment: `const type varName = statement ? valueIfTrue : valueIfFalse;`

Comment: It's only declared in it's scope (between { and }). Only way you can do is with #define's not in the {} scope but please don't. They are horrible.

Comment: Your variable will go out of scope at the `}`, so it won't exist anywhere else than inside the `if (true) {...}` block. It wouldn't make sense any other way. Because if the condition was `false`, what would happen then? Would the variable not exist? What would happen in the code that uses the variable?

Comment: Looks like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/455871). What are you trying to solve?

Comment: Do you mean static? Otherwise the variable lives only in the scope.

Comment: I want the variable to exist if the condition is true or false. I am interested in the value of it. The condition will happen only ONCE  in the program  For this one time, when condition is true I want to have a change in the variable and  this will not change never. So, with this way I can understand that the condition has been satisfied only once.

Comment: @Dani: There's a standard way of achieveing "calling once": I've appended it to my answer.

Comment: @Bathsheba τhank you very much! I will try it and Ι will come back to let you know if the problem has been resolved.

Comment: @dani Your wording is kind-of unclear to me. Does it mean, that 1) you have a variable set to some initial value, and 2) if some condition is true, the variable is assigned another value? And, finally, after this moment, you want this variable to be treated as constant? If so, you can easily create a constant reference (alternatively a pointer) to that variable and access it through that reference only.

Comment: @DanielLangr Yes, I mean that I have a variable with some initial value and if some condition is true, the variable is assigned another value.But after this moment I want this value to be constant and never change even we run again the program. Can this be done or it is impossible?

Comment: Τhat is, to make a variable constant after a condition is true and the first initial value of the variable can be deleted for ever.

Comment: @dani As I wrote, create a constant reference to that variable and use this reference instead of that variable after it has a proper value. What is wrong with this approach? I am afraid you cannot make some variable constant at some moment at runtime.

Comment: @DanielLangr You are right! The technique you suggested is the right one. Thank you very much for your time and help!!!

Answer (score 4):

The main issue is that you can't refer directly to the variable outside the `if` body.

The simple workaround is to have a pointer of your type in the outer scope set by default to `nullptr`, then use a `static` or `thread_local` in the `if`, and set the outer scope pointer to that:

```
Foo* f = nullptr;
if (/*condition*/){
      static Foo foo;
      f = &foo;
}
```

You can make the types `const` as required. Another approach would be to use a `std::variant`, or `std::optional`.

If however you are implementing something as a means to getting a section of code to run only once, the standard way of doing that is to use

```
std::once_flag flag; 
std::call_once(flag, []{/* ToDo - code here */});
```

Comment: Didn't you mean `std::optional`?

Comment: @DanielLangr: That's a good idea (why not answer?)! Didn't think of that at the time: I'm still on C++11.

Comment: I just thought you had a typo, that is, that you meant `std::optional` but wrote `std::variant` by mistake. Since I don't see why `std::variant` would fit here (both are from C++17). I think your answer is pretty good — use a pointer with pre-C++17, or `std::optional` since C++17.

Comment: For me a `std::variant` would allow you to establish the type in the outer scope, then narrow it (or whatever the correct term is) in the `if` block. But my feeling is that the pointer way was the simpler.